# use every and filter function together in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two arrays of strings. where I want to see if one array has any value common from another array and then print the array which has unique values only. For this I am performing a JavaScript every function on both the arrays which returns a Boolean if one array has values common from another array and then if the condition is true, I am doing a filter on an array to show the data. Here are the arrays:

```
marketingCarrierCode: ["DL", "AA"]
operatingCarrierCode: ["AA", "AA"]
```

now I am doing every and filter like this way:

```
const hasSameCarrierCode = operatingAirlineCode.every(
    code => marketingAirlineCode.indexOf(code) !== -1,
  );
  const listOfOperatingCarriers = operatingAirlineCode.filter(
    code => marketingAirlineCode.indexOf(code) === -1,
  );
```

this gives me:

```
hasSameCarrierCode: true
listOfOperatingCarriers: []
```

now I want to perform every and filter function in one function, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want the same output as above? `hasSameCarrierCode: true
listOfOperatingCarriers: []`

Comment: "...if one array has values common from another array": please note that your function does not perform _this_ check. Instead it checks if one array has _only_ values common from the other one. If you're really interested in the first condition you should use `Array.some()` instead of `Array.every()`

Comment: @SanaMumtazm yes

Comment: @lbsn I want to do exactly what code I written, maybe I could not describe properly in words, I now just want to combine these every and filter function in one function rather using these two functions.

Comment: @ashfaq In this case you just don't need the first function, as pointed out in davood's answer below. `Array.filter()` will always return an empty array if the first condition is true, so you can just check the length of `listOfOperatingCarriers`

Comment: @ashfaq But I guess there must be some typo in your question, because right now your logic doesn't make much sense. If you know that every item in `operatingAirlineCode` is also in `marketingAirlineCode` (first function), what's the point of filtering the items that are not (second function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't need to first function. You can use thie:

```
const listOfOperatingCarriers = operatingAirlineCode.filter(
  code => marketingAirlineCode.indexOf(code) === -1,
);

listOfOperatingCarriers.length !== operatingAirlineCode.length   => true,
listOfOperatingCarriers => []
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, "for each" code in `operatingCarrierCode`, you are checking if it exists in `marketingAirlineCode`. If any code doesn't exist in `marketingAirlineCode`, then test is failed i.e. `hasSameCarrierCode` should be false. Also, you add the uncommon code in list `listOfOperatingCarriers`. All this can be combined into one `forEach` as below:

```js
const marketingAirlineCode = ["DL", "AA"]
const operatingCarrierCode = ["AA", "AA"]

let hasSameCarrierCode = true;
let listOfOperatingCarriers = [];

operatingCarrierCode.forEach(code => {
  if (marketingAirlineCode.indexOf(code) === -1) {
    hasSameCarrierCode = false;
    listOfOperatingCarriers.push(code);
  }
})

console.log(`hasSameCarrierCode:`, hasSameCarrierCode)
console.log(`listOfOperatingCarriers:`, listOfOperatingCarriers);
```

A much smaller version could be:

```js
const marketingAirlineCode = ["DL", "AA"]
const operatingCarrierCode = ["AA", "AA"]

const listOfOperatingCarriers = operatingCarrierCode.filter(code => marketingAirlineCode.indexOf(code) === -1);
const hasSameCarrierCode = listOfOperatingCarriers.length === 0;

console.log(`hasSameCarrierCode:`, hasSameCarrierCode)
console.log(`listOfOperatingCarriers:`, listOfOperatingCarriers);
```